# how to calculate percentage difference with cmp command

Tags: shell, scripting, difference, cmp

I am aware of cmp command in linux which is used to do byte-by-byte comparison, could we build upon this to get percentage difference.
Example I have two files a1.jpg and a2.jpg
So when I compare these two files using cmp. Could I get percentage of difference between these two files.
example: a1.jpg -> has 1000 bytes and a2.jpg has 1021 (taking bigger file as reference)
So could get percentage difference between two files i.e No of byter differing/Total bytes in larger

Looking for some shell script snippet. Thanks in advance

Comment: `cmp` stops comparing at the first dofference. This is not a tool for this. I think you have to write one yourself. I believe you could read both file byte by byte, compare, increment some "difference_count" variables, compare sizes of the files and calculate the division. What have you tried? There is `cmp -i` and `cmp -b` but I have a feeling it would be a good solution. Also, for each change, `cmp` would need to re-open the file then fseek with `-i`, which would be slower then just implementing that in a short C program.

Comment: I could also see such way: print each byte from both files with a newline, use `join --nocheck-order` to compare them and print nonmatching lines from both streams. Then count the lines, this will be the number of bytes differing.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a file script with the following content - let us call this file `percmp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIFF=`cmp -l $1 $2 | wc -l`
SIZE_A=`wc -c $1 | awk '{print $1}'`
SIZE_B=`wc -c $2 | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ $SIZE_A -gt $SIZE_B ]
then
    MAX=$SIZE_A
else
    MAX=$SIZE_B
fi
echo $DIFF/$MAX*100|bc -l
```

Be sure that it will be saved with Linux encription.
Then you run it with the two file names as arguments. For example, assuming `percmp.sh` and the two files are in the same folder you run the command:

```
sh percmp.sh FILE1.jpg FILE2.jpg
```

Otherwise you specify the full path of both the script and the files.

The code do exactly what you need, if you need reference:

- `#!/bin/sh` tells how to interpret the file
- `cmp -l` lists all the different bites
- `wc -l` number of rows (in the code: lenght of the list of different bites -> number of different bytes)
- `wc -c` size of a file
- `awk` text parsing (to get ONLY the size of the file)
- `-gt` **G**reater **T**han
- `bc -l` performs the inputed division

Hope I helped!

Comment: Wow, great. Instead of `wc -c $1 | awk '{print $1}'` you can just `wc -cc <"$1"`. Remember to quote your variables. Using backticks \` is tricky and it's usage is [discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) - use `$( .. )` instead.